# Is there a potential earth leakage or is it something else?

Tags: ac, mains, grounding, electrical, earth

I'm facing an issue in my house since last Christmas. When the lights or appliance with motor in any room are turned off/on the TV would go out and come back on in a short span (as if the power went out and came back in a second). I recently had some mishaps where my two older PCs PSU blew up. But I though tit was just the old PSUs had its end of life. Then recently my new under one month old PSU in new PC built just died.

So, I took my multimeter and checked the voltages first from a  220V kitchen outlet that is directly wired from the panel next room and it shows Phase-Phase=223V & both Phase-Ground=220V. Then I tried the other 110V outlets in the house and they all have Neutral-Phase 130V, Neutral-Ground=0.4V & Phase-Ground=49.2V. Next trying other 220V outlets also gave Phase-Phase=223V and both Phase - Grounds=49.2V. So, except for the 220V outlet directly from the breaker in the kitchen something is off. Anyone here can help me out with what could be the potential situation? Because of this pandemic situation I have held off calling an electrician until now.

Comment: Call an electrician - you probably have an open or high resistance Neutral somewhere.

Comment: @PeterBennett Thank you for the reply. I'll have it checked out by an electrician asap.